# Get the XMlNode content from object marked as serializable

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class `Image` implementing `ISerializable`:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "IMAGE")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ImageTypeConverter))]
public class ImageResource : ISerializable {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TYPE")]
    public string Extension{
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I just want to know if we can get the xml node for an object of this class?
Suppose this object is serializes as

```
<IMAGE TYPE=".mpg"/>
```

I want to get this Node content as string.

Comment: What do you want to get, exactly? a string with xml serialization? the XmlNode inside a document? Maybe an example would make your question clearer.

Comment: The `[Serializable]` attribute is ignored by XML Serialization.

Comment: So is the `ISerializable` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind got the answer from below
[link text](http://shico.blogspot.com/2008/05/serialize-and-deserialize-object-tofrom.html)

Answer (score 1):

The XML representation does not exist until you serialize the instance. Once you serialize it, you can manipulate it as XML.

Hint: you should be able to serialize directly into an `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImageResource));
    ser.Serialize(instance);
}
```